# rails 3 absolute link to generated url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am looking into generating urls which look like https://mywebsite.com/user/check_email_confirmation/46cee41bc2044104aff8cf7746687ea8

for the famous "please click this link to confirm your email".

So I have a route which I intend to use for this in my routes.rb:

```
  resources :user do
    collection do
      get  'check_email_confirmation/:generated_url', :to => 'user#check_email_confirmation'
    end
  end
```

Now, my trouble is to generate the full address above. I cah generate the SHA (46cee41bc2044104aff8cf7746687ea8) part, but how do I write the "https://mywebsite.com/user/check_email_confirmation/" part in my view?

Added view's code:

```
<p>Please click <%= url_for(:action => 'check_email_confirmation', :controller => 'user', :only_path => false, :id => @confirmation_url) %> to confirm your e-mail address.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `id:` with `generated_url:`.

You could also simplify the `url_for`ing with naming the route by `as:` in routes

```
get  'check_email_confirmation/:generated_url', to: 'user#check_email_confirmation', as: :confirmation
```

More on this at http://viget.com/extend/rails-named-routes-path-vs-url

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for helping me out on this, and for the valuable link!

Answer (score 0):

```
get "check_email_confirmation/:id" => "users#check_email_confirmation", :as => "check_email_confirmation"
```

Comment: The view is the mail body that I send to the user where he can click  the link to the action you wrote. How can I not write it?! I tried writing <%= url_for(:action => 'check_email_confirmation', :controller => 'user') %> but that leads an error. Can't we use url_for with an action in a resource?

Comment: ok, try to add :id => user.generated_url in the same url_for tag

Comment: See view's code above (added to the post). Here is what it yields:`No route matches {:action=>"check_email_confirmation", :controller=>"user", :id=>"d1176be458fff6e9b3527bf526e89ebf8cd3276d7fcfb99a11ca284049d06273"}`